# Read the file check the sequence

Tags: perl

I am reading a file like this

```
1
one
2
two
3
three
three
three
four
five
5
```

In this I want check the sequence `one two three four five` and print how many times three is present.

My code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open(tempp1,"<$temp1") or die "Could not open file $temp1: $!";
 my $count = 0;
while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
  if ($line eq "one") {

  while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
   if ($line eq "two") {
    
   while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
    if ($line eq "three") {
     $count++;

     while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
      if ($line eq "four") {

       while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
        if ($line eq "five") {
         last;
}}}}}}}}}}
print "$count\n";
close tempp1;
```

Output is printing :1
How to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems is that you immediately start looking for `four` as soon as `three` is encountered when you should be looking for both `three` and `four`.

The simple answer is to replace

```perl
   while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
    if ($line eq "three") {
     $count++;

     while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
      if ($line eq "four") {
```

with

```perl
   while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
    if ($line eq "three") {
     $count++;

     while(my $line=<tempp1>) {
      if ($line eq "three") {
        $count++;
      }
      elsif ($line eq "four") {
```

But it's unclear if that produces the desired result. Consider the following input:

```
           # Possible Sequence 1   Possible Sequence 2
           # -------------------   -------------------
one        # one                   one
two        # two                   two
three      # three                 three
three      # three                 three
four       # four                  
three      #                       three
three      #                       three
three      #                       three
four       #                       four
five       # five                  five
           # -------------------   -------------------
           # 2 instances           5 instances
```

Should `count` be 2 (stop counting when `four` is found) or 5 (the largest possible)? The above solution would return 2.

Also, note that you don't currently check if `four` and `five` were found, but you suggested that this is required.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it does not work is pointed out on ikegami's answer.

But, also, as an alternative, you may consider using a regex-based solution.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_content;
do { # we use a do block to change the line terminator locally
    local $/ = undef; # set line terminator as undef so we will read whole file
                      # when we would try to read a line
    open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
    $file_content = <$fh>; # now it reads the whole file
    close $fh or die $!;
};

if ($file_content =~ m/ ^ one\R two\R ((?:three\R)+) four\R five $ /ixm) {
    print "Number of 'three's is: " . split m/\R/, $1;
    print "\n";
} else {
    die 'I could not find a valid sequence';
}
```

(Note that since this reads the file as a whole, you need enough memory to hold it)

Then you try to match the file content using this regex:

```
m/
    ^                     # start of line
        one\R             # literal 'one' + end of line character/s
        two\R 
        ((?:three\R)+)    # One or more (+) "three" + end of line repetitions
                          # everything holded on a capturing group (outer parentheses)
        four\R 
        five
    $                     # end of line (a character is not required)
/ixm # i = ignore case
     # x = ignore whitespace and allows comments
     # m = ^ and $ match begin and enf of line (instead of begin and end of string)
```

Which serves as two purposes:

- Check that you find a valid 1, 2, 3, ..., 4, 5 sequence
- Capture the 3, ..., 3 part

The 3, ..., 3 part is captured on the first capturing group (`$1`) Then you split that content by lines and the number of lines you have is the number of `three`s

Answer (score 1):

I would look for the lines like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;

my $counter=0;
my $threes = 0;
my @lines_to_match = qw(one two three four five); 

open( my $fh , "<" , "file.txt") or die $OS_ERROR;
while ( my $line = readline($fh) )
{
  if ( $counter < scalar(@lines_to_match) and $line =~m/$lines_to_match[$counter]/ )  
  {
    $counter++;
  }
  $threes++ if $line =~m/three/;
}
close($fh);

print "counter = $counter - threes = $threes\n";
```

You can check if all items are matched with

```
print "true" if $counter == scalar(@lines_to_match);
```

You can also check the last match was "three" by using one of the following

```
$threes++ if $line =~m/three/ and $counter==3;
$threes++ if $line =~m/three/ and $line=~ m/$lines_to_match[$counter-1]/;
```